# "workqueue_trust" what does this thread do?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I see a thread called "workqueue_trust" running in background when the mp3 is played while screen is turned off. What does this thread do ? This thread seems to wakeup every 100ms... Is there a way to find out what this thread does ? I used ftrace, however, I don't see much about this "workqueue_trust" thread in the trace...